# How to statically type a string property within a React component using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that is a text field abstraction.

```
<TextField
    label="Enter your user name"
    dataSource={vm}
    propertyName="username"
    disabled={vm.isSaving}
/>
```

`vm` is a view model object injected as a prop into the view. `username` is a property within `vm`. `vm` uses mobx and `<TextField />` mutates the `vm` object as the user types.

How can I use typescript to restrict the `propertyName` field to only properties of the `vm` object?

Notes:

- I use `<TextField />` in multiple places, where each time the `vm` object is different and does not share a common interface.

Comment: `const vm = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 42,
};

let k: keyof typeof vm;
`?

Comment: @zerkms What does keyof typeof do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You can do this with a generic component as well, the compiler will infer `T` correctly based on usage. `dataSource` will be typed as `T` and `propertyName` will be `keyof T` meaning any string that is a property name of `T`:

```
export class TextField<T> extends React.Component<{ label: string, dataSource: T, propertyName: keyof T, disabled: boolean }> {

}

let vm = {
    username :"",
    isSaving: true  
}

let text = <TextField
    label="Enter your user name"
    dataSource={vm}
    propertyName="username"
    disabled={vm.isSaving}
/>

// error here
let textErr = <TextField
    label="Enter your user name"
    dataSource={vm}
    propertyName="usernames"
    disabled={vm.isSaving}
/>
```

---

**Edit 2**

To be able to assign a string to the value of the field specified as `propertyName` we must make a change in the way use our generic types to ensure that `dataSource[propertyName]` is verifiable to be a `string`. We will change the generic parameter to be the property name and use a mapped type to constrain the type of the property is `string`:

```
interface IProps<K extends string> { label: string, dataSource: { [P in K]: string }, propertyName: K, disabled: boolean }
export class TextField<K extends string> extends React.Component<IProps<K>> {
    constructor(props: IProps<K>) {
        super(props);

        props.dataSource[props.propertyName] = "";
    }
}
```

---

We can do this using generic functional components and let the compiler infer the generic parameter based on the value of `vm`

```
const TextField = function<T>(p: { label: string, dataSource: T, propertyName: keyof T, disabled: boolean }) {
    return <div />;
}

let vm = {
    username :"",
    isSaving: true  
}

let text = <TextField
    label="Enter your user name"
    dataSource={vm}
    propertyName="username"
    disabled={vm.isSaving}
/>

// Will produce an error
let texterr = <TextField
    label="Enter your user name"
    dataSource={vm}
    propertyName="username2" 
    disabled={vm.isSaving}
/>
```

Comment: Good solution. I do need to maintain state within the component however, so I can't use a stateless functional component.

Comment: @Learner you can use a class as well, just tried it out, the compiler will infer the type correctly

Comment: Works perfectly. Except inside the component, I do get a strange error when mutating the vm property with the following syntax. propertyOwner[propertyName]. Error: [ts] Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'

Comment: @Learner there is no constraint that the property should be string,. Currently at lunch, will add a solution to make this work when I get back to a PC

Comment: @Learner Added a version where you can assign a `string` to the property dynamically